# Getting multi-threading to work with a list using python pexpect

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, pexpect

I wrote a simple python pexpect script to ssh into a machine and perform a action. Now I need to do this action to multiple servers. I am using a list to hit all of the servers concurrently using multi-threading. My issue is due to everything being ran concurrently, each thread is running on the same server name. Is there a way to concurrently have each thread only run one of the listed servers?

```
    #! /usr/bin/python
#Test script

import pexpect
import pxssh
import threading
import datetime



currentdate = datetime.datetime.now()
easterndate = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(0, 3600))

#list of servers
serverlist = ["025", "089"]

#server number
sn = 0


ssh_new_conn = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
  def run(self):

    index = 0
    sn = serverlist[index]
    print sn
    username = '[a username]'
    password = '[a password]'
    hostname = '%(sn)s.[the rest of the host url]' % locals()
    command = "/usr/bin/ssh %(username)s@%(hostname)s " % locals()
    index = index + 1
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    print command
    p = pexpect.spawn(command, timeout=360)

    ***do some other stuff****

for i in range(len(severlist)):
  t = ThreadClass()
  t.start()
```

[update]
I may just trying doing this with a parent thread that calls the child thread and so forth....although it would be nice if multi-threading could work from a list or some sort of work queue.

Comment: On a separate note: you may want to consider using password-less authentication (key-based) for this kind of activity.  Makes life so much simpler, and you can do away w/ pexpect, and simply use supprocess.Popen to do the ssh'ing.

Comment: Or, even more simply, use [`paramiko`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) instead of trying to script the `ssh` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with "everything being ran concurrently". You're explicitly setting `index = 0` at the start of the `run` function, so of course every thread works on index 0.

If you want each thread to deal with one server, just pass the index to each thread object:

```
class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, index):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__()
        self.index = index
    def run(self):
        sn = serverlist[self.index]
        print sn
        # same code as before, minus the index = index + 1 bit

for i in range(len(severlist)):
    t = ThreadClass(i)
    t.start()
```

(Of course you'll probably want to use `serverlist` instead of `severlist` and fix the other errors that make it impossible for your code to work.)

Or, more simply, pass the `sn` itself:

```
class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sn):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__()
        self.sn = sn
    def run(self):
        print self.sn
        # same code as last version, but use self.sn instead of sn

for sn in severlist:
    t = ThreadClass(sn)
    t.start()
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use a global variable, just make it global, and put a lock around it:

```
index = 0
index_lock = threading.Lock()

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global index, index_lock
        with index_lock:
            sn = serverlist[index]
            index += 1
        print sn
        # same code as first version
```

However, you might want to consider a much simpler design, with a pool or executor instead of an explicit worker thread and list of things to work on. For example:

```
def job(sn):
    print sn
    # same code as first version again

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(job, serverlist)
```

This will only run, say, 4 or 8 or some other good "magic number" of jobs concurrently. Which is usually what you want. But if you want exactly one thread per server, just pass `max_workers=len(serverlist)` to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor.

Besides being a whole lot less code to read, write, get wrong, debug, etc., it also has more functionality—e.g., you can get results and/or exceptions from the servers back to the main thread.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the "server" mistype I was trying to clean the code up before I posted it.

Comment: I don't know why I did not see that I already had the index available to pass. Thank you again.